# JS closure: returning a private scope incremental counter value within an object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a `counterIncrement` method that can be reused by other methods and returns the `counter` variable every time the method is called.

```
var myClass = {

    //counter method
    "counter": (function(text){
        var counter = 0;
        return function(text) {
            counter++
            console.log(text+counter);
        }
    })(), //how do you return this function without resetting the counter every time it is called?

    //every time this method is called the counter increases
    "myMethod": function(text) {
        myClass.counter(text);
    }
}

myClass.myMethod('the counter is at '); //the counter is at 1, 2, 3, etc.
```

Essentially what I'm trying to build is a reusable `counter` method that will instantiate new counter values and increment independent of each other.

```
var myClass = {

    "counter": (function(text){
        var counter = 0;
        var this.text = text;
        return function(this.text) {
            counter++
            console.log(this.text+counter);
        }
    })(),

    "firstMethod": function(text) {
        myClass.counter(text);
        //do something that uses the counter
    },

    "secondMethod": function(text) {
        myClass.counter(text);
        //do something completely different that instantiates new private counter
    }
}
```

Comment: you say you want new counter. In what sense?

Comment: maybe this.counter would be more appropriate? A private counter value (integer) is called by a method; the counter integer will increase every time the method is called, and the value is independent of other this.counter values that are instantiated by other methods calling the same function.